# 450gb of root space full in 3hrs, unable to login

Tags: linux, hard-drive, linux-mint

I have installed Linux mint 20.3 on a desktop pc along side windows one month ago. Mint has 450gb of root space. When I logged in in the morning, it had 74gb of free space. During this session it got completely filled and I couldn't do anything. Tried to restart but can't login. I have not done anything that will eat up space this much quickly. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check the logs. Likely something is triggering endless error messages. That "something" should be addresses ASAP.